# Media Foundation Encoder MF_E_TRANSCODE_NO_MATCHING_ENCODER

Tags: media, h.264, encoder, wmv, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to convert from wmv to mp4. 
First of do I need to implement my IMFTransform to do this ?
Do i need to convert the video to MFVideoFormat_I420 ?

As far as I know if you create the topology correctly this should be handled automatically.
So I created my profile showed in the

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

but i get a MF_E_TRANSCODE_NO_MATCHING_ENCODER.
I have windows 7 so, i should have the encoder.

Also Does anyone know where the source code for that tutorial is. It is not under SDK samples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show code - noone knows what is wrong.

Take a look at this transcoding sample, which comes with source code and does exactly what you are trying to do: transcoding from ASF into MP4.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mf/archive/2009/12/02/mfsimpleencode.aspx

> MFSimpleEncode.exe - This is a command line tool that transcodes files
>   from one media format to another. The source code is provided to use
>   as a reference if you write your own transcode application. This tool
>   uses the Media Foundation transcode API, which was introduced in
>   Windows 7.
>
> Examples:
>
> 1. Transcode ASF to MPEG-4:
>
>    MFSimpleencode.exe –i Input.wmv –o output.mp4 –p TranscodeProfileMPEG4.xml

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right. I ll post the code.
But that example uses the MFCreateTranscodeTopology. That also works for me but I need to create my own topology. Bwcause that function takes in source object , path to outFile, profile(AAC and H264) params and Create the topology. 

I need to write my custom sink because I do not want to write the output to a file.

Comment: @EvrenBingøl I also facing same problem.I am not cnverting one file to another.In my case I am reading from h264 camera and wrting in the file.I am getting same error on  MFCreateTranscodeTopology().Plz Help